# How can I scroll to an element on page load?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
<div class='title' id='about'>About Us</div>

<a class='mm' href='about.php#about'>About Us</a>
```

I have a sticky positioned element above the target div so the `.title` div is not visible after loading the page

How can I scroll up the document after loading, for example for 54px, so the target div comes into view?

I tried this, without success:

```
$(window).on('load', function(){
    if(!window.location.hash == ''){
        window.scrollBy({top: 54, behavior: 'auto'});
    }
});
```

Comment: Where is the "target div"? Your question is not clear.

Comment: @Md.RakibulIslam - target div has id `about`. It is clear from `href='about.php#about'`

Comment: FYI, those aren't hashtags. They're URL hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need JS at all.
If a sticky header gets in the way of the scrolled-to *Target* element, use in CSS:

```css
/* body or your scrollable wrapper */
scroll-margin-top: 54px;
```

given your sticky page nav or header occupies that `54px` height.

Answer (score -1):

on page reload, cant you just re-direct page to `href=about.php#about`